# Typescript: define a primitive within another

Tags: typescript, template-literals

The issue is that when I receive a response back from an API, it is the most inconsistent response I think I've dealt with so far. Anyways, what I am trying to do is give more structure with Typescript. For example:

```js
interface Response {
  foo: string
}
```

The problem that I have is that *EVERYTHING* is a string: foo could be `"true"` || `"123"` || `"undefined"` || `"null"`

but there are some values that I know will be there. So I know that this field will always be of type `string` but within that string is going to be a `number`

what I would like is to create a class or an interface that looks like this:

```js
interface Response {
  foo: string<number>
}
```

because now I just have notes next to everything like:

```js
interface Response {
  service: string // string("true")
}
```

Comment: you can update the title of your question as : TypeScript: stringify primitive type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
type Primitives = boolean | number | null | undefined

type MakeString<T extends Primitives> = `${T}`

// "undefined" | "null" | `${number}` | "false" | "true"
type Result = MakeString<Primitives>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbhAzlAvFAIwHsiAbCAQwDsoAfKKgVyQIjjocdNI8aoBMIAMwRUI-AFATQkKAFkKAawgBlYIioBzADwAVKBAAewCAJzxkqDNgB8eKAAMAJAG9dAXwcSA9N6gAiPkERMX5-Dn8mbnD6ZxcmFjZPCKEKUiwIGID1RkzpcGgAJWwuYHsFZTUNHQsUNEwsGyA)

Please see [distributive-conditional-types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) if you are confused by `T extends any`

**TL;TR**
Wrapping `T` into template literal string distributes the union.

**Thanks @Clarity**

Comment: It does work without distributive types, i.e. `type MakeString<T extends Primitives> = ${T}` or am I missing smth?

Comment: @Clarity you are right, did not try it. Seems that template literal already distributes it. Thank you!

Comment: thanks that clears things up! this type of information was challenging to find within the typescript docs